# Is there a way to have consistent gutters when using the Susy grid system?

Tags: layout, grid, susy-compass

I am using and learning Susy and noticed that when using fluid or "magic" container style, the gutters scale along with the rest of the columns if the browser is resized. I am concerned that the smaller gutters reduce the space between the columns to the point where content in adjacent columns becomes too close.

Is there a way to preserve the size of the gutters and only resize the columns? Or is there another approach I can take to address the reduced horizontal space between content columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Susy 1.x - besides using a static grid - but the feature is coming in 2.0.

If you change the column-count at different breakpoints, the gutter size will increase with fewer columns.

Comment: This is what I was thinking... reduce the number of columns at specific breakpoints so that the gutters do not get "compressed." Thank you for creating Susy and for supporting it here!